# Selenium tests with Hibernate

Tags: database, testing, selenium

I would like to apply Selenium tests on my web application, but it seems that I can't modify my database during those tests.

More precisely, I would like to insert and delete items from my database.

Does anyone have a solution ?

I use Appfuse, Hibernate and Spring in order to access my database ?

Comment: I can understand why you would want to read from your database but I don't understand why you need to write to it in your tests.

Comment: I agree, I'll try another way.

Comment: Personally, I would use TestNG and then create a DataProvider that queries the database using JDBC.